# spring batch table size limit

Tags: sql, spring-batch

I am currently trying to read a table with about 5 million records using spring batch. After several minutes I got the follwing exception: org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException:

```
Failed to initialize the reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:153) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:104) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:311) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:205) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:152) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:137) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:320) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at library.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at main.singlethreaded.loadtesting.LoadTestController.read(LoadTestController.java:151) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader.openCursor(JdbcCursorItemReader.java:133) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doOpen(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:443) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:150) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]
    ... 76 common frames omitted

2021-09-01 09:32:09.620  INFO 29816 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [step-1] executed in 18m44s257ms
2021-09-01 09:32:12.295  INFO 29816 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=transferJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{currentTime=1630505594578}] and the following status: [FAILED] in 18m51s81ms
```

I am using a simple query:

select * from table

When using a query with a limit like

select * from table limit 10000

it works well.

Is there a limit to the number of rows in a table that can be read by spring batch?

Comment: There is no limit to the size of the input table. You are facing this issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3968 which has been fixed and planned for the next release, v4.3.4/v4.2.8. That said, according to the stack trace you shared, the issue happens when attempting to translate the original `SQLException` into a `DataAccessException`. I would be curious to know what the original `SQLException` is about. Can you try to get that info and share it? What is the fetchSize set on the reader? This could be used as a hint to some JDBC drivers to stream results (or not).

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine can you please create an answer with your comment so I can accept it?

Comment: I added an answer. Thank you upfront!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit to the size of the input table. You are facing this issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3968 which has been fixed and planned for the next release, v4.3.4/v4.2.8.

That said, according to the stack trace you shared, the issue happens when attempting to translate the original `SQLException` into a `DataAccessException`. So I would be curious to know what the original `SQLException` is about.